# How can I test my app in 12.9 inches screen size in Windows 10?

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, emulation

I need to test my flutter app in a tablet with 12.9 inches. As I know this is only Ipad-Pro screen size. I have no apple products, working on windows 10. I looked up for emulators from android studio there was no emulator with 12.9 inches. How can I test that (I want to launch my app not only screen images.) Is there a way I can work with an Ipad Pro emulator in windows 10 or resizing the emulator screen? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open AVD Manager in Android Studio
2. Click "Create Virtual Device"
3. Click "New Hardware Profile"

You can configure hardware profile (screen size,resolution etc).